# OpenCV duplicate locations of detected items

Tags: python, image, opencv, object-detection

Hello :) i have a problem with OpenCV detection items on screen, I wanted to make a memory game bot, It works, but there are duplicate card positions

```
        # load the image to find
        image = r'C:\\Users\\Komputer\\Desktop\\screen\\' + str(x) + '.png'
        templateim = pyscreeze._load_cv2(image, grayscale=False)
        (w, h, _) = templateim.shape

        # get screenshot
        screenim_color = img
        screenim_color = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenim_color), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        Nsearch = 2  # number of times to search
        center_locations = []  # list to store locations
        for k in range(Nsearch):
            result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenim_color, templateim, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)  # template matching
            (_, _, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(
                result)  # get the location  where the correlation coefficient is maximum (This is the top-left tip of the box surrounding the template)

            cv2.rectangle(screenim_color, maxLoc, (maxLoc[0] + h, maxLoc[1] + w), (0, 0, 255),
                        -10)  # mask the detected region by drawing a solid rectangle over it

            center_loc = (int(maxLoc[0] + h / 2)+165), int((maxLoc[1] + w / 2) + 212)  # get the center location
            center_locations.append(center_loc)  # append to list
            print(center_locations)
        for x in range(2):
            pyautogui.click(center_locations[x])
            time.sleep(1.05)
    time.sleep(10)
```

The output of console, seems like :

```
[(354, 471), (489, 471)]
[(353, 472), (488, 472)]
[(623, 297), (488, 648)]
[(355, 822), (220, 296)]
[(353, 296), (219, 296)]
[(353, 295), (624, 295)]
[(354, 295), (219, 295)]
[(488, 821), (220, 821)]
```

it looks like it detects the same item multiple times next to each other, is there an option to fix this?

Comment: the operation you want is called "non-maximum suppression". you could simply test all the boxes against each other and if a pair overlaps mostly, discard one of them.

Comment: I compared the point centers and skiped those close to each other in the loop, it worked, thank you for the hint